# ActionMailer mail with inline attachments not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am using rails 3.2.8. This is how mailer class looks like:

```
class Newsletter < ActionMailer::Base
  default :charset => "UTF-8",
          :from => "\"Example\" <info@example.com>"

  def campaign
    attachments.inline['image1.gif'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/image1.gif")
    attachments.inline['image2.gif'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/image2.gif")
    attachments.inline["image3.jpg"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/image3.jpg")

    mail(:to => "mytest@example.com", :subject => "Test")
  end
end
```

When I send it, I only receive one attachment without main body. When I look at mail source I see other parts, but I don't understand why they are not showing as they should.

I checked other similar questions but nothing helped.

Please, help me. Do you need more code to solve the problem?

Regards,
Tomaž

Comment: Out of interest would you not consider using `wicked_pdf` - https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf food for thought.

Comment: Sorry David, but I don't see how this gem could help in this situation?

Comment: what do you mean by you receive only one attachment without main body. Is there any error code or anything that you can provide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mention the attachments in your mail-content view file?

Add this code in you mail-content view file:

```
<%= image_tag attachments['image1.gif'].url %> 
<%= image_tag attachments['image2.gif'].url %> 
<%= image_tag attachments['image3.gif'].url %>
```

You can also have a look at a more detailed explanation available at:
http://technical-feeds.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-add-attachments-and-inline.html